# Can my G Suite admin see my browsing history if: I am in incognito mode on iPad Chrome?

Tags: privacy, chrome, ios

Can my G suite admin see by browsing history if: I am in incognito mode on iPad Chrome?
iPadOS beta 3.
I'm signed in with a G Suite account.

If they are monitoring me, is it visible? Is there any way to make it invisible?

I am not on their network and there are no Chrome extensions installed. No monitoring software is visible when I go to the apps menu, and the security section in the Google Account page shows no third-party apps with account access.

Comment: The admin of your computer/iPad that the browser is running on, or of the network you're connected to? The answers would be "yes, if they have keylogging software or similar", and "yes", respectively.

Comment: Admin of the G Suite account that I’m logged into Chrome with.

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this is very simple, and follows from the [ten immutable laws of security](https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/)

> - If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your computer, it’s not your computer anymore
> - A computer is only as secure as the administrator is trustworthy

In your case you have a device someone else administers. If you don't trust your administrator, you cannot trust the device with whatever you are about to do. This **universal** to absolutely all computer systems.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @MechMK1 In my opinion no better answer is possible with the information given. We do not know what the configuration is. There could be a SSL stripping proxy configured. The blunt answer is that if you can't trust your admin, then you have no security.